# How to block https website with iptables

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firefox, dns, iptables

I want to block some https website like youtube.com, facebook.com.

I know that we can't block that using url rules. since the url is encrypted.

So I tried to block all DNS queries which contain the domain I want to filter. So I added the following rule:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -m string --domain yahoo.com -j DROP
```

But the youtube keep running. But after some time of inactivity (about 15 min) youtube is blocked.

Are there some explanation?

How I can force youtube to be blocked immediately?

Comment: The 15 minutes is likely due to DNS caching and the dns time to live settings, however I'm unsure how to stop it immediately

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are doing will have an effect, but there are several problems:

- Browsers and operating systems cache DNS lookups.  They don't necessarily cause a full DNS lookup each time a site is loaded.
- Some browsers may try alternate things if DNS appears blocked (such as contact its own DNS server), because they think there is a network issue.  Google Chrome may do this.
- Google Chrome and other browsers may soon implement "DNS over HTTPS" which means doing anything to port 53 would not have any effect, as it wouldn't be using that for DNS at all.
- Blocking by IP address will work for awhile until Youtube's IP address changes for some reason.
- Savvy users may change DNS servers unless you've blocked that ability administratively on your systems.

> How I can force youtube to be blocked immediately?

The "right" way to do what you want is to institute a "Man-In-The-Middle" transparent HTTPS interception proxy that can filter HTTPS traffic.  You then tell the proxy to block any URL with `youtube.com` in it.

You can't just simply look for `youtube.com` on 443 as it's encrypted, as you probably figured out.

One you can play with on a local machine to see how it works is Burp Proxy - it's meant for testing, not managing the traffic of many users though.  But will enable you to learn the concepts.

You will have to install the proxy's SSL certificate on every machine that uses the proxy to avoid security warnings.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and it's a valid question. The "right" way is illegal in most countries. You shouldn't be asking users to install your certificate in any public access type scenario (libraries/schools/cafe)

Answer (score 3):

Your command is:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -m string --domain yahoo.com -j DROP
```

First your blocking only udp and port 53

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -s 172.217.0.0/16 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -s 172.217.0.0/16 -j DROP

iptables -I INPUT 2 -s 157.240.0.0/16 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD 2 -s 157.240.0.0/16 -j DROP
```

First you need to block the INPUT chain as that is where the data comes in.  The FORWARD chain may be un-neccesary for your needs.  Then I did a ping on youtube, and then I did a whois on that IP to see what block they owned.

Finally, I blocked all there IP so we don't need to bother with dns lookups.

Answer (score 2):

```
#nslookup youtube.com

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   youtube.com
Address: 172.217.16.46
Name:   youtube.com
Address: 172.217.20.206

iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -p tcp -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 172.217.16.46 --dport 80 -j DROP
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -p tcp -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 172.217.20.206 --dport 80 -j DROP
```

source: http://forum.oszone.net/post-692775-5.html

or

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.0.0.0/24 -p tcp -m string --algo bm --string ".youtube.com" -j DROP
```

source: http://moshelpers.ru/?q=node/71

or
The first example, we have a machine-gateway for the local network, there we create a rule for blocking for example the resource youtube.com it will look like this code:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m string --string "youtube.com" --algo kmp --to 65535 -j DROP
```

To block addresses on the Linux machine, edit the rule a little code:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m string --string "youtube.com" --algo kmp --to 65535 -j DROP
```

source: http://sudouser.com/blokirovka-nezhelatelnyx-url-s-pomoshhyu-iptables.html

and that would break tcp connection at once and without timeout only for `-p tcp` you can try the following

```
-j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

source: http://forum.ixbt.com/topic.cgi?id=76:10833

I'm sorry, all sources - russian sites:)

Answer (score 1):

As stated in comments by @djsmiley2k you certainly face dns caching. This means that your machine does not request again the DNS server for a given domain if it recently resolved it.

To enforce immediate blocking of domain, you should enforce DNS cache flushing.
Depending on your OS, commands will differ. You can find examples [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-debian-ubuntu-flush-clear-dns-cache/)

As a summary, immediately after adding the iptables rule, you can try either :

```
$ service nscd reload
```

or

```
$ service dnsmasq restart
```

or

```
$ rndc restart
```